# Can I check condition in template match in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I want to check variable in template match, is it possible?

like:

```
 <xsl:template match="*:Item and $MODE='PURCHASE'">
```

So template should check variable `$MODE='PURCHASE'` as well

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow it, though some XSLT 1.0 processors do (I believe Xalan is one). However, your syntax using 'and' is your own invention, and quite unrelated to anything in the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in XSLT 1.0.

In XSLT 2.0 one can have variable references -- in the predicates of the template match pattern.

**For example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="MODE" select="'PURCHASE'"/>

 <xsl:template match="*:Item[$MODE='PURCHASE']">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t xmlns:x="some:x">
  <x:Item>someText</x:Item>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
  someText
```